# Validate many SQL statements for correctness

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have about 150 reports generated from SQL statements. These reports are saved independently from the server. Some generated from sprocs, some from table-valued functions, but mostly just SQL statements.

Now the server goes through a big refactoring of tables and sprocs. And I need a way to validate that all the reports are still running, as it is possible the changes will break the reports.

One way to validate that all the reports are valid - run them and lookout for errors.

The problem - some of the reports are very heavy and include aggregation of of many tables with many joins with millions of records.

Is there a way to validate SQL statements without actually executing them?

I'm working with SQL Server 2008 and have ability to apply C# processing to the statements. Ideally I'd like a way to validate the reports often and without much effort, i.e. 10 times a day. So making a schema-only copy of DB is not an option.

Comment: The real issue here sounds like a lack of a change management system, wherein these reports should be tested in a dev environment where running them wouldn't be an issue. Alternatively you could make modified versions of the reports that only select a few rows to ensure they run.

Comment: There are many issues here, never mind the change management and other good practices. But I am where I am and I need to make this work. So you are saying add `top 1` after every `Select` keyword?

Comment: That may not apply to all the reports, but that's where I'd start. `SELECT 1 FROM ...` might prove useful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the table [sys.sysdepends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190325%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) which will help with your stored objects.

For embedded SQL you could [SET ROWCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for the batch.  This will terminate the query after compilation (and hence name resolution and object binding) but before large quantities of data are processed.